# How to get row count of a web table each and every time when we click something in table

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, collections

I have a table in which 1st column of 1st row having expand  (+) button [if we click (+)button some rows will be added to the table] ..When ever i clik the expand button i need the new row count ...Please help

*This is the code*

List rows = m.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='table']/tbody/tr"));
        int r=rows.size();

```
for(int i=1;i<=r;i++)
    {


        WebElement plus=m.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='table']/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[1]")); 

    if(plus.isDisplayed())  //*** expand(+)  button***
    {
        m.driver.findElement(By.xpath(//div[@id='table']/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[1])).click();   

    }


    }
```

Comment: Show what you've done so far. Add the Html code or link to the page if possible.

Comment: hi can you give us a sample web app as per your scenario

Answer (score 0):

Using webdriver you can use to count all rows. Note the name is plural:

```
driver.findElementsBy(By.xpath("//table[@id='however-you-find-it']//tr")).getSize();
```

It is OK for simple tables like:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Row 1, Column 1</td>
        <td>Row 1, Column 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
        <td>Row 2, Column 2</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Depending on how the table is constructed, some variations may be needed. You may perhaps need to include `//table[...]//th]` in the count, if table headers are also important.

If the table has nested tables, and you want only to count rows of the top level table, do not use `table[...]//tr` as it will include nested rows as well, but rather `table[...]/tr` or `table[...]/tbody/tr`, where single slashes indicate immediate child, not any descendent of type tr.

Answer (score 0):

```
// To get total row count

public int getRowCount() {

    List rows = m.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='table']/tbody/tr"));
    return rows.size();
}
```

it  iterate for loop and when for loop condition is false it return updated size.

```
public int updatedCount() {

    for(int = 0 ; i < = getRowCount() ; i++) {
        //..your code 
    }

    return  getRowCount();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the initial count of the table

   `List rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='table']/tbody/tr"));
   int initialRowCnt = rows.size();`
2. Click on the expant (+) button

   `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='table']/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[1]")).click();`
3. Get the new row count

   `List rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='table']/tbody/tr"));
   int initialRowCnt = rows.size();`

Hope this helps